Is it possible to snipe this text with css so I can hide it?
So, basically, I have this HTML example autogenerated by code:
<h1>I want to "display:none" this text <span>But keep visible the span content</span></h1>

Is there anyway to hide the text NOT inside the span with just CSS?

Is it compulsory to use display: none;? If not you can give font-size zero to h1 and default to span

We'll you could hide it using visibility, and set it to visible on the child span. You'll need some additional CSS to fix the placing.
But it's probably better to fix the autogenerated part.


h1        { visibility: hidden; }
h1 > span { visibility: visible; }
<h1>I want to "display:none" this text <span>But keep visible the span content</span></h1>




Nice solution!! I think about setting font-size:0 for the h1 and font-size:16px for the span, but it has repercussions on SEO I imagine

If it's about SEO, you might want to use visibility: collapse and not hidden.

But some JS that will split the text into a hidden element might be cleaner. Or a 'read more' button if you want the user to be able to see it should they want ;)
